# How to send emails in Twilio Functions without SendGrid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I know we can use SendGrid and there are examples provided but SendGrid is awful and everything goes to spam with the non-dedicated IP accounts (yes, even after enabling DKIM and all that other stuff). All the free IPs are blacklisted and SendGrid support won't remove them or give me non-blacklisted IPs.

Is there any other way to send emails without using SendGrid using **Twilio Functions**? Can I somehow use NodeMailer and set it up with Gmail? That would be the ideal solution.

Comment: yes you can use nodemailer to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With Twilio Functions [you can install any npm module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/packages) you like as long as it [doesn't require native extensions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/packages#limitations) (look out for anything that depends on `node-gyp` for example).

As NodeMailer has no dependencies, you can absolutely use it. Just head to the [Configuration section in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure) and add NodeMailer as a dependency. You can then `require` it in any of your Twilio Functions and use it from there.

Let me know if that helps at all.